# To send mail in JSP using servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I need the mail program that have to send with all type of host.I have used smtp but it supports only gmail.In my project,Mail have to send by company login.There may lot of company login and they may have different type of mail accounts...I have to write a single program to support all type of mail accounts.

```
package com.admin;

/**
 *
 * @author asp.net
 */
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 * A utility class for sending e-mail messages
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class EmailUtility {
    public static void sendEmail(String host, String port,
            final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
            String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp") ;

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(message);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
}
```

Comment: What a challenging and unique opportunity your employer has given you, I wish you luck and I think you're going to need it.

Comment: When you tried to use SMTP for multiple Types Of Mail Account what error did you get ? Share the code

Comment: There are different smtp servers for different types of email accounts.

Comment: I ddnt get any type of error..its keep on trying...I have implemented on local host it works well in local host but i have deployed in linux server it doesnt working.

Comment: i have posted the code that im using..

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?  Are you actually getting a `Session` object and a `Message` object?

Comment: Yes..It worked with local host..when i deployed to linux server..it does not sending anything.Is there program varies for windows and linux??

Comment: Well, there could be a million reasons for this, unrelated to the actual Java.  For example, whatever machine you're using as your SMTP host might be accessible from your desktop but not from the Linux box, due to the way your network has been configured.  Firewalls, DNS servers and stuff like that.

Comment: Priya, I think what you need to do is to get up from your desk, go downstairs, and talk nicely to one of your network administrators.  They'll be able to help because they know your network.  The users of Stack Overflow probably won't be able to.

Comment: Anybody help me to send mail with all types of accounts such as gmail,yahoo ans so on with single mail server..

Comment: @Priya does my answer solves your problem.If not then reply what error are You getting?

Answer (score 0):

The below is woking code .I have tested It in Centos 6

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "SendMail", urlPatterns = {"/SendMail"})
public class SendMail extends HttpServlet {

    public final String from = "from@gmail.com";
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
          // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "to@gmail.com";
     // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned


      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

      // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
    //  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);


                properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

      // Get the default Session object. 
                Session session ;

                session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, "password");
                    }
                });

        session.setDebug(true);


      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
          MimeMessage  message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }



}
```

This is a servlet and you can change this code to class and if you want you cant pass fileds to function of that class.